# NancyFx F# App with parameter

Tags: f#, nancy

I am trying to get this example translated from C# to F#

```
public class MyModule : NancyModule
{
    private IMyDependency _dependency;

    public MyModule(IMyDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;

        Get["/"] = x =>
        {
        };

        // Register other routes
    }
}
```

(source [1](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Bootstrapping-nancy))

However adding a parameter to constructor

```
  type HelloModule(dependency) as self = 
    inherit NancyModule()
    do
      self.Get.["/"] <- fun _ -> "Hello" :> obj
```

(source [2](http://blog.nancyfx.org/hello-nancy-world-in-f))

results in a run-time exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Something went wrong when trying to satisfy one of the dependencies during composition ...

How can I correctly add a dependency like a data-source to the code? Or, generally, how do I pass something from outside of HelloModule to the inside?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this might be caused by not specifying the type of the `dependency` parameter of the constructor in your F# code. This would result in the F# compiler assigning that parameter a *generic* type, and then Nancy's dependency injection framework doesn't know what to inject.

Try the following and see if it fixes your problem:

```
type HelloModule(dependency : IMyDependency) as self = 
  inherit NancyModule()
  do
    self.Get.["/"] <- fun _ -> "Hello" :> obj
```

P.S. Naturally, for this to work, you'll also need to have some type that implements the `IMyDependency` interface, and have told the Nancy framework about that type. From [this part of the Nancy documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Bootstrapping-nancy#part-2---manually-registering-dependencies) that you linked to, it looks like merely declaring the type is enough, but if that's not actually enough then you'll have to register the type manually. I'm not familiar enough with Nancy to give you specific advice there beyond what the documentation says.